# How can I add my textbox inside regex to dynamically delete the a word?

Tags: c#, regex, richtextbox

I have ***txtSrcUserID***   textbox. I want to remove the user input word from the sentence below.

**This code helps me to delete the "USER1". from the sentences below on richtexbox1. but depending on the user input the word will change so I need to make it dynamically to delete the word...**

```
  Regex reg = new Regex("(ALTER TABLE .+ REFERENCES\\s+)\"USER1\"[.](.+)");
  richTextBox1.Text = reg.Replace(richTextBox1.Text, "$1$2");
```

***my sentence***

```
ALTER TABLE "GRADE" ADD CONSTRAINT "GR_ENR_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("STUDENT_ID","SECTION_ID") REFERENCES "USER1"."ENROLLMENT"("STUDENT_ID","SECTION_ID") ENABLE;

ALTER TABLE "GRADE" ADD CONSTRAINT "GR_GRTW_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("SECTION_ID","GRADE_TYPE_CODE") REFERENCES "USER1"."GRADE_TYPE_WEIGHT"("SECTION_ID","GRADE_TYPE_CODE") ENABLE;
```

**after using my code sentence will be modified like this:**

```
  ALTER TABLE "GRADE" ADD CONSTRAINT "GR_ENR_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("STUDENT_ID","SECTION_ID") REFERENCES "ENROLLMENT"("STUDENT_ID","SECTION_ID") ENABLE;

    ALTER TABLE "GRADE" ADD CONSTRAINT "GR_GRTW_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("SECTION_ID","GRADE_TYPE_CODE") REFERENCES "GRADE_TYPE_WEIGHT"("SECTION_ID","GRADE_TYPE_CODE") ENABLE;
```

***I want something like this so where can I add txtSrcUserID inside the code below ***

```
 Regex reg = new Regex("(ALTER TABLE .+ REFERENCES\\s+)\"txtSrcUserID\"[.](.+)");
 richTextBox1.Text = reg.Replace(richTextBox1.Text, "$1$2");
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this:

```
Regex reg = new Regex(string.Format("(ALTER TABLE .+ REFERENCES\\s+)\"{0}\"[.](.+)", txtSrcUserID.Text));
```

Comment: Exactly what did not work? Because if I call `string.Format("(ALTER TABLE .+ REFERENCES\\s+)\"{0}\"[.](.+)", "USER1");` the output is `"(ALTER TABLE .+ REFERENCES\\s+)\"USER1\"[.](.+)"`